# Why fs.copySync didn't work as expected?

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, fs

I try copy and paste files from one directory to another, and there's error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3', although path and files exist. If I give arg to fs.copeSync "manually" it work well

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrPath.length; i++) {
      let source = arrPath[i].replace(/\\/g, "\\\\"); // change one slash to double
      let destiny = pathToCollect.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\") + "\\\\" + path.parse(arrPath[i]).base; //destination directory
      console.log(source);// e.g. D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3

      console.log(destiny);// D:\\collect\\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3

      try {
        fs.copySync(source, destiny);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);// Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3
      } finally {
        console.log("success");
      }
    }


    //this work well, as expected

    fs.copySync('D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3', 'D:\\collect\\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3');
```

Comment: Do you mean `fs.copyFileSync()`?  I would guess you have a backslash problem.  Windows path backslashes are a real pain to get right in Javascript.

Comment: Can you show the content of: `arrPath` please?

Comment: arrPath is array of strings: ["D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3", "D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - MnogoMebeli.mp3", "D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ВИ.mp3", end etc

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. This: `\\\\` makes no sense. Have in mind that what you see on `stdout` and what you see in your code are not the same things.

```
const path = 'D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3';

console.log(path);
```

Will output: `'D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3'`, and that's how Javascript will treat it, as a single `\`, which is a valid path. You're trying to achieve `\\` (What you see in your code) by using `\\\\` but windows does not need double backslash, it only needs one.

You were trying to emulate: `'D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3'` by printing: `'D:\\\\transfer\\\\roliki\\\\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3'`

So, I don't have all the context but, these two lines:

```
let source = arrPath[i].replace(/\\/g, "\\\\"); // change one slash to double
let destiny = pathToCollect.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\") + "\\\\" + path.parse(arrPath[i]).base; //destination directory
//                                                    ^^ this is wrong, very wrong, use path.join
```

Should be (Assuming `arrPath[i]` & `pathToCollect`) are valid paths.

```
const basename = path.parse(arrPath[i]).base;
const source = arrPath[i]; // I need to see what `arrPath` is
const destiny = path.join(pathToCollect, basename); //destination directory
```

You should **always** use `path.join` instead of using string concatenation.

**UPDATE:**

Your `arrPath` array is wrong.

If you have those paths hardcoded, you should escape backslashes, otherwise, `\t` is a tab, `\r` is carriage return.

```
const arrPath = [
    "D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3", 
    "D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - MnogoMebeli.mp3", 
    "D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ВИ.mp3"
];
```

It should be:

```
const arrPath = [
    "D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3", 
    "D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\\Реклама - MnogoMebeli.mp3", 
    "D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\\Реклама - ВИ.mp3"
];
```

```js
const wrongPaths = [
    "D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3", 
    "D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - MnogoMebeli.mp3", 
    "D:\transfer\roliki\rolikiNOW\Реклама - ВИ.mp3"
];

const correctPaths = [
    "D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\\Реклама - ALESA04032016.mp3", 
    "D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\\Реклама - MnogoMebeli.mp3", 
    "D:\\transfer\\roliki\\rolikiNOW\\Реклама - ВИ.mp3"
];

console.log('Bad:')
for(const path of wrongPaths)
  console.log(path);

console.log('Ok:')
for(const path of correctPaths)
  console.log(path);
```

Comment: /*I remade code like belowe, but there's same issue,
  anyway thanks for recommendation*/
  
  let pathToCollect = path.normalize("D:/collect");
  let source = path.normalize(arrPath[i]);
  let destiny = path.join(pathToCollect, path.basename(source))

Comment: Now that I have the actual data, I will try when I get home.

Comment: @КогодеевАлександр check updated answer, your `arrPath` array is wrong.